# Prove the inequality $f'(0) \ge -\sqrt {2}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on the open interval $(-1,1)$ such that $f(0)=1$. Suppose $f$ also satisfies $f(x)\geq 0$,  $f'(x)\leq 0$, $f''(x)\leq f(x)$  for all $x\geq0$

> Show that $f′(0)\geq−{\sqrt[]{2}}$.

All I am to see in this question is that $f(x)$ is decreasing in $(0,1)$ but I don't  know how  to prove this inequality  can somebody give me a hint on how to proceed with it.

Comment: I would assume the fundamental theorem of calculus would come in handy here. Possibly the mean value theorem is enough, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the function is  twice differentiable, by Taylor polynomial Theorem,  it can be written as:

$ f(h) = f(0) + f'(0)h + f''(h')h^2/2$ with $ 0<h'<h$.

Now using  $f''(h') \leq f(h') \leq f(0)$, we get:

$ f(h) \leq 1 + f'(0)h+ h^2/2$

Using  $ 0 \leq f(h) $ we get:

$ 0 \leq 1 + f'(0)h + h^2/2$

So by simplifying we get:

$ -1/h - h \leq f'(0)$

As, $ 0\leq h<1 $ is arbitrary, we can set it to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and we get:

$ -\sqrt 2\leq f'(0)$

Comment: I do not have much knowledge about Taylor  polynomial  theorem  , so I have a query why did you use $f''(h')$ instead of $f''(0)$? Can you please explain that part to me

Comment: this Theorem says that for every (n+1)times differentiable function, and an arbitrary point $a$ in its domain, you have:
$f(x) = \frac{f(a)}{0!} + \frac{f'(a)}{1! }x +...+\frac{ f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} x^n+ \frac{f^{n+1}(\theta)}{(n+1)! } x^{n+1}$
for a $\theta$ between $a$ and $x$.

Comment: if you use $f^{n+1}(a)$ instead of $f^{(n+1)}(\theta)$(or in your case, $f''(0)$ instead of $f''(h')$, you get another version of this theorem:
for every (n+1)times differentiable function, and an arbitrary point $a$ in its domain:
$f(x) = \frac{f(a)}{0!} + \frac{f'(a)}{1! }x +...+\frac{ f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} x^n+ \frac{f^{n+1}(a)}{(n+1)! } x^{n+1} + R(x) $
with $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^{(n+1)}} = 0$ which roughly means $R(x)$ (The remainder)  is very small for $x$ near $a$.

Comment: Thanks now I've understood the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint: see that:

$$f''(x)\leq f(x)\implies f'(x)f''(x)\geq  f'(x)f(x) \implies \frac{1}{2}[(f'(x))^2]'\ge \frac{1}{2}[(f(x))^2]'$$

Integrating we get $$(f'(x))^2 -(f'(0))^2\ge (f(x))^2 -(f(0))^2$$